# Currency sign after the price class in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress 3rd party theme and it limits me because for customization i need to (guess what) pay even more... even for small things like this...

I have this class which shows me the "€" currency sign after the price "1000 €"
But i have a price range like this: 1000 - 2000 €

How can I put the currency sign after the 1000, so it will look like this (1000 € - 2000 €) ??

HTML code :

```
<span class="post-rice"><span class="text">Prices:</span>6000 - 7000</span>
```

At this moment i use this CSS code:

```
.post-rice:after{content:"€";}
.post-rice:before{content:"€";}
```

But with those CSS codes I have the price like this:( € 1000 - 2000 € ) ... The :before method is not correct. Can you please give me an advice ?

Comment: can you share the HTML also. Do you have any limitation to add price as text only or can you use html elements for displaying price, like `<span>1000</span>`?

Comment: <span class="post-rice">
         <span class="text">
          Prices:          </span>
         6000 - 7000        </span>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML there, where people are more likely to see it. Comments are transient and subject to deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you are looking for. Right now the HTML interprets your span as one block of text, so the `:before` selector will put content in front of the whole text block.

**HTML**

```
<span class="post-rice">
  <span class="text">Prices:</span>
  <span class="price">6000</span> - <span class="price">7000</span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.price::after {
  content: "€" // alternatively use "content: &#8364;" 
}
```